# How do you bundle aws-sdk-js into a Serverless Framework optimized package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

AWS SDK for node.js can not be run through [browserify](http://browserify.org/) due to [how the SDK is loaded](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/696)

I want to included a newer version of the AWS SDK for node then what is included in lambda but I also want to optimize (via browserify) my lambda node.js code.

How do I pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

The [JAWS AWS Module system](https://github.com/awsm-org/awsm) (aka awsm) allows for this functionality via an attribute in the awsm.json metadata file that specifies how the lambda code is packaged.

Specifically the `lambda.package.optimize.exclude` and `lambda.package.optimize.includePaths` defined in the [lambda configuration options](https://github.com/awsm-org/awsm#lambda-configuration-options) section of the awsm.json spec.

The `exclude` attribute specifies node modules that should be excluded from the optimization process (under the covers it is just using [browserify exclude](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#ignoring-and-excluding)).  In the `exclude` attribute you simply specify `['aws-sdk']`.  You must then tell JAWS to include `aws-sdk` in the zip by putting its path in `includePaths`.

The `includePaths` attribute is a list of paths relative to the `back` directory that are pulled in as-is into the zip file before deployment.

For a complete example see the [awsm sample](https://github.com/awsm-org/awsm-images/blob/master/awsm/thumbnail/awsm.json)